# Adding data to one table adds duplicated data to the relational table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have to tables which have a relation. Table `discipline` lists the possible disciplines. Table `participant` lists the participants of the tournament. If I add a participant, it adds the chosen disciplines again to the `discipline` table.

Model class `discipline`:

```
public class Discipline
{
    public Discipline()
    {
        Participants = new HashSet<Participant>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int DisciplineId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Participant> Participants { get; set; }
}
```

Model class `participant`:

```
public class Participant
{
    public Participant()
    {
        Disciplines = new HashSet<Discipline>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int ParticipantId { get; set; }
    public string Forename { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Discipline> Disciplines { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Result> Results { get; set; }
}
```

This is the method to bind the list of entries of the discipline table to a multiple select box.

```
private void BindData()
{
        using (var db = new ParticipantsContext())
        {
            var disciplines = db.Disciplines.ToList();
            DisciplinListBox.ItemsSource = disciplines;
            DisciplinListBox.DataContext = disciplines;
        }
}

private void OK_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        using (var db = new ParticipantsContext())
        {
            var selectedDisciplines = DisciplinListBox.SelectedItems;
            ICollection<Discipline> selectedDisciplinesCollection = new List<Discipline>();

            foreach (Discipline selectedDiscipline in selectedDisciplines)
            {
                Discipline discipline = new Discipline
                {
                    DisciplineId = selectedDiscipline.DisciplineId,
                    Name = selectedDiscipline.Name
                };
                selectedDisciplinesCollection.Add(discipline);
            }

            var participant = new Participant
            {
                Forename = ForenameTextBox.Text,
                Name = NameTextBox.Text,
                Disciplines = selectedDisciplinesCollection
            };

            db.Participants.Add(participant);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        this.Close();
}
```

I expect to add a `participant` and the relation between `discipline` and `participant` in the `dbo.ParticipantDisciplines` table - but without adding a new `discipline`.

What am I missing?

Complete code if wanted: https://gitlab.com/svanschu/EasyCalc/tree/master/DecksummeWPF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new objects which cannot be tracked by EF. You can attach them like below prior save.

```
...
db.Disciplines.Attach(discipline); 
selectedDisciplinsCollection.Add(discipline);
```